# Multiple properties for one instance

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm trying to create one data structure.

Data structure's definition is, One bucket can have multiple transactions and each transaction is attached with one message and also can have many key value pairs as properties.(One transaction can have 1 to N properties(Key-Value pair)

Here is my code snippet

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class TransactionDemo {

        private List<Transactions> transactions = new ArrayList<Transactions>();

        public void createTransaction(String inp) {

            this.transactions.add((new Transactions(inp)));

        }

        public List<Transactions> getTransactions() {

            return transactions;
        }

    }



public class Transactions {

    String transactionMesage;
    private List<Properties> transactionsProperty = new ArrayList<Properties>(); 


    public Transactions(String inp){

        this.transactionMesage = inp;
    }

    public void setTransactionProperty(String key, String value){

        this.transactionsProperty.add(new Properties(key, value));

    }
}




public class Properties {

    String key;
    String value;

    public Properties(String key, String value) {

        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;

    }

}




public class MainTransactionClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        TransactionDemo createDataStructure = new TransactionDemo();
        createDataStructure.createTransaction("Alan");
        createDataStructure.createTransaction("Jon");
        System.out.println(createDataStructure.getTransactions().get(0).transactionMesage);
        System.out.println(createDataStructure.getTransactions().get(1).transactionMesage);

    }

}
```

I'm able to manage, Multiple transactions in bucket(List) with one associated message but same message can also have more than one properties as key value pair. And every Transaction should be having its own set of properties and associated message.

May I know How can I achieve where every transaction could have its own set of Key value pairs ?

Comment: Then change `String message` to `Map<String, String> message` or `List<Properties> message`

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn, But how can I manage where every transaction is having its own map ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `message` type to `Map` or list of `Properties`:

```
public class Transactions {
    private List<Properties> message; // Or Map<String, String> message
    private List<Properties> transactionsProperty;
}
```

Comment: Okay that I can do, but dont you think so when ever I get new Transaction the reference name should also be changed to HashMap, because every transaction should be having its own set of key value pairs...?

Comment: You want to change `List<Transaction>` to `Map<String, Transaction>` ?

Comment: I just want every Transaction Instance should be having its own separate Map<String, String> or List<Properties>  instance ...!

Comment: Each transaction has a separately `transactionsProperty` already